# Using a QCombobox delegate item within a QTreeview

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qtreeview, qcombobox

I've been trying to utilize Qt's MVC type programming for a particular problem I'm trying to solve. Essentially I want a QTree which has cells populated with a variety of QComboBoxes.

I've created my delegate class and the Comboboxes seem to be populated correctly, additionally I'm using a custom slot to be called when the comboboxes index is changed however I am unable to cast the sender object into a combobox or find another way in which I can determine the index selected in the combobox.

If anyone could help out I'd be very grateful, I'm just starting to work with Qt's MVC and I feel like I'm close but I just cant figure this bit out.

Heres a bit of the mainwindow class executeLogicWindow.cpp

```
executeLogicSetupWindow::executeLogicSetupWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::executeLogicSetupWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

int maxRow = 3,maxCol = 2;
treeModel = new QStandardItemModel(maxRow,maxCol,this);
treeItemDelegate = new controlObjectItemDelegate(this);

//tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate); // Column 0 can take any value, column 1 can only take values up to 8.
ui->dynamicObjectTreeView->setModel(treeModel);
ui->dynamicObjectTreeView->setItemDelegate(treeItemDelegate);



for(int row = 0;row< maxRow;row++)
{
    for(int col = 0;col< maxCol;col++)
    {
        QModelIndex index = treeModel->index(row,col,QModelIndex());
        //int value = (row+1) * (col+1);
        //treeModel->setData(index,QVariant(value),Qt::EditRole);
        treeModel->setData(index,"Click to Edit",Qt::EditRole);
    }
}


connect(treeModel,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)),this,SLOT(OnTreeItemCBChanged(QStandardItem *)));


ui->logicSetupTableWidget->setColumnCount(8);
ui->logicSetupTableWidget->setRowCount(1);
ui->logicSetupTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Input Condition;Val A;Comparison;Val B;Reaction;Output Action").split(";"));

methodIndex = 0;

addComboRow(ui->logicSetupTableWidget->rowCount()-1);

}

executeLogicSetupWindow::~executeLogicSetupWindow()
{
delete ui;
}


void executeLogicSetupWindow::OnTreeItemCBChanged(QStandardItem *testItem)
{

QComboBox* combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(sender());

//QComboBox* combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(testItem);

QModelIndex testIndex = testItem->index();
qDebug() << testItem->index();
int row = testItem->index().row();
int col = testItem->index().column();
QVariant value = testItem->data();

//qDebug(testItem);
if (combo)
{
    qDebug("It worked");
}
else
{
    qDebug("Guess its fucked");
}
}
```

heres the delegate class controlobjectdelegate.cpp

```
#include "controlobjectitemdelegate.h"
#include "QAbstractItemDelegate"
#include "QAbstractItemModel"


controlObjectItemDelegate::controlObjectItemDelegate(QObject *parent) :
QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget* controlObjectItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
QComboBox *cellComboBox = new QComboBox(parent);
cellComboBox->addItems(QString("Test 1;Test 2;Test 3").split(";"));
return cellComboBox;
}

void controlObjectItemDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
int value = index.model()->data(index,Qt::EditRole).toInt();
QComboBox *cellComboBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
cellComboBox->setCurrentIndex(value);
}

void controlObjectItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
QComboBox *cellComboBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
QStringList value;
for(int i=0;i<cellComboBox->count();++i)
{
    value.append(cellComboBox->itemText(i));
}


model->setData(index, cellComboBox->currentText(), Qt::EditRole);
}

void controlObjectItemDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Comment: shows the code of your controlObjectItemDelegate.

Comment: Well, what is the type of the sender of the signal that you receive? :)

Comment: I just added the delegate class cpp code and im not sure of the sender type. I just know its not a qcombobox, which is I guess the real root of the problem. is there a particular way you suggest to find the sender type other than just trying to cast it to a bunch of different things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must correct the code of your delegate, in the method `setEditorData` when using `index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole)` this contains a string that can not be converted to int, so you have always set as index to 0, so when you want to select another option the first item appears as selected, you must change that code to the following:

```
void controlObjectItemDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString value = index.model()->data(index,Qt::EditRole).toString();
    QComboBox *cellComboBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
    cellComboBox->setCurrentText(value);
}
```

There is no method to get the delegate editing widget, but if we can get its values for it we can store that value in a new role:

```
void controlObjectItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QComboBox *cellComboBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(editor);
    model->setData(index, cellComboBox->currentText(), Qt::EditRole);
    # save the index of the QComboBox in the role Qt::UserRole + 1
    model->setData(index, cellComboBox->currentIndex(), Qt::UserRole+1);
}
```

and then in the slot you get that value:

```
void executeLogicSetupWindow::OnTreeItemCBChanged(QStandardItem *testItem)
{
    QVariant variant = testItem->data(Qt::UserRole+1);
    if(variant.isValid()){
        qDebug()<<variant.toInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome that looks to have done what I wanted, thanks so much!!
I hadn't really known much about using Qt roles but after looking more into the documentation I guess the userroles can be used to assign data to a model item?